# How to display multiple video stream in one window

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying some video processing exercises, and wondering if there is a way to display multiple video streams into one window a la pyplot.subplot command for the images.

I've tried using subplot syntax, but using it freezes the program, so any alternative source would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at OpenCV.  At each time step you might want to generate a composite image and ask OpenCV to display the composite image in one window.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to display multiple videos(e.g 2-videos can be displayed for dual core processor) at a time for that you have use OpenMP. It is possible if your using opencv. And it is pretty easy Only you have to enable OpenMp in your property sheet.

Comment: This is in substance more of a comment than an answer. You could, for example, provide a screen grab of what you are proposing.

Comment: @ShawnMehan I don't privileges to comment. If anyone interested i ll update this with a code. !! Thank you i ll keep them  in mind.!!